# How do you get data from an HTML multiple listbox using an Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get data from a multiple listbox in IE, using a macro in Excel

HTML

```
<html>
<header></header>
<body>
<select size="11" multiple="" name="List"><option value="1111111111@bob.com>1111111111@bob.com">1111111111@bob.com</option><option value="2222222222@bob.com>2222222222@bob.com">2222222222@bob.com</option><option value="3333333333@bob.com>3333333333@bob.com">3333333333@bob.com</option><option value="4444444444@bob.com>4444444444@bob.com">4444444444@bob.com</option><option value="5555555555@bob.com>5555555555@bob.com">5555555555@bob.com</option><option value="6666666666@bob.com>6666666666@bob.com">6666666666@bob.com</option><option value="7777777777@bob.com>7777777777@bob.com">7777777777@bob.com</option></select>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get excel to open it up in IE

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "c:\users\smahony\desktop\test.html"
ie.Visible = True

While ie.busy
    DoEvents
Wend
```

But I'm running into problems trying to get a value. I've tried:

```
Range("A2").Value = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).Option(1)
```

Also tried GetElementByTagName("select"), GetElementByName("List"), getelementsbyname("List")(0), and I've tried using .Item(1), instead of .Option, as I've seen in a few examples I googled.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There maybe more than one(or two) `select` tags in the web page(i.e.  document object).  You could use `for each` loop to identify which `select` tag you want.  Beside, there is a typo, `GetElementsByTagName` not `GetElementByTagName`.